# Help identifying an SMD FET in a Philips Hue power supply

Tags: power-supply, identification, components, surface-mount

One of our Philips Hue lamps died recently and I found that the power supply is the reason.
Two resistors burned (most likely due to overvoltage from the mains).

However, there is an SOT-23 component I couldn't identify. It probably is an [AFN501DEA](http://www.alfa-mos.com/datasheet/HVMOS/AFN501DEA.pdf), but I'm not sure.

Check the photo below, "501DE".
Unfortunately, I didn't find an alternative/replacement component for this. Could somebody help me find one?

[image: component - question]

[image: hue power supply]

[image: ps top view]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be it's an [SMS501DE](http://secos.com.cn/datasheet/products/MOSFET/SOT-23/SMS501DE.pdf). These are marked "501DE" according to the datasheet.

Googling "SMS501DE replacement" even shows places where you can buy one.